# Drawing with citations

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

I would like to draw diagrams with citations. The advantage of using LaTEX is that I don't have to manually input the citations whenever the citations change within the document. This poses a lot of problems when a manual software is used to draw diagrams. A writer may have to wait till  the document is finished, manually check the citations and input them into the diagram. I have included a sample diagram but I currently do not have a working example for other details because I do not know where to begin.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

with `forest` is simple:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={              % style of nodes in the tree
  draw, semithick, rounded corners,
   text width = 24mm, text badly centered,% <-- "align=center" doesn't work
                        % style of tree (edges, distances, direction)
         edge = {draw, semithick, -stealth},
       anchor = north,
         grow = south,
forked edge,            % for forked edge
        s sep = 8mm,    % sibling distance
        l sep = 8mm,    % level distance
     fork sep = 3.5mm,  % distance from parent to branching point
     tier/.option=level,
           }
 [Big Class
  [Class A
    [Proposal A1 \cite{...}\\
     Proposal A2 \cite{...}]
  ]
  [Class B
    [Proposal B1 \cite{...}\\
     Proposal B2 \cite{...}]
  ]
  [Class C
    [Proposal C1 \cite{...}\\
     Proposal C2 \cite{...}]
  ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

**edit:**
similar result you can obtain with `tikz` using `trees` tikz library:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
every node/.style = {draw, rounded corners, text width=28mm, align=center,
                     anchor=north},
level distance = 12mm,
sibling distance = 32mm,
edge from parent fork down
                        ]
 \node {Big Class}
    child{ node {Class A}
        child{ node {Proposal A1 \cite{...}\\
                     Proposal A2 \cite{...}}}
        }
    child{ node {Class B}
        child{ node {Proposal B1 \cite{...}\\
                     Proposal B2 \cite{...}}}
        }
    child{ node {Class C}
        child{ node {Proposal C1 \cite{...}\\
                     Proposal C2 \cite{...}}}
        };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! This looks very nice. I would like to know more about using forest for this purpose! Such as increasing the branches and sub-branches of the tree and adding colour to the nodes if required

Comment: for coloring of node just ad to `for tree` options for example `top color = teal!10, bottom color = teal!50,`.  for more subbranches see how is done in example (quit simple). however, if you will stuck in this effort, don't hesitate to ask for help on this site :-)