# Graph like figure with citations using Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

I would like to create a graph like figure (shown in the image) with text and citations related to text. I manually created the image shown, but I would like to use Tikz (or anything else) to create it in Latex as I want to insert citations as means to visually display related work pertaining to my research. I picked the numbers for the citations randomly. In fact, I would like to replicate that image **exactly** as is with the shapes and colors (with modifications to text and citations). Is this possible? I would love some help in being able to this.

Thank you.
[image: Related Work]

Comment: This is possible. Note however that it is best to show some own effort. What have you tried so far? Can you show us some code? Question addressing a specific issue are of more value to future visitors than complete do-it-for-me.

Comment: Thank you. I started out using these examples [drawing-with-citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/411359/drawing-with-citations) and [hierarchical diagram](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/hierarchical-diagram/). However, I found out that both are "trees" and getting them to have 2 parents was a bit difficult. [Here](https://www.overleaf.com/read/qqhsdhdfksxm) is how far I've gotten.

Comment: It is good to see that you tried to accomplish this on your own. You should however add this code to your question and make the question self-contained. (I added the code now)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out the Forest package. Here's a simple example I created for you:
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
   for tree={ellipse, edge+=->, l=3cm, inner sep=0.5cm}
   [Main, draw=blue!100, fill=blue!10
     [Type-1 \cite{itemone}, draw=green!50, fill=green!20
       [Technique-1 \cite{itemtwo}, draw=green!50, fill=green!20]
       [Type-3 \cite{itemthree}, name=type3, draw=yellow!50, fill=yellow!20
        [My Technique, top color=red!20, bottom color=red!100, rectangle]
       ]
     ]
     [Type-2, name=type2, draw=purple!50, fill=purple!20
       [Technique-1, draw=purple!50, fill=purple!20]
     ]
   ] 
   \draw[-latex] (type2) to (type3);
\end{forest}

\begin{thebibliography}{10}
\bibitem{itemone} 
Item One

\bibitem{itemtwo} 
Item Two

\bibitem{itemthree} 
Item Three
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I copied this code after this was posted. Sorry I didn't update the post. It has gotten me started. Now it need to figure out the spacing and the shapes for different notes. I'll report my progress here.

Comment: @Skillmon The OP's original code is commented out in the Overleaf document. The code that is not commented out was what I provided in my post.

Comment: @RogerIyengar sorry for misunderstanding then.

Comment: @shaun I edited the answer to add spacing and a different shape. You can see some additional examples of shapes [here](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/node-shapes/).

Comment: @RogerIyengar again this was my fault, as I've mistakenly added your code claiming it was his. Really sorry for the mess I've created. I've removed the code.

Comment: @Skillmon I didn't realize that. Thank you for taking it out though!

Comment: @RogerIyengar Thank you for this code. I've tried it and it works for my needs. If I hit a roadblock that I can't solve I will update this post.

Comment: @shaun You're welcome! Glad to hear this meets your needs.

Answer (score 3):

I'd draw this "manually" just with the `positioning` library for positioning and some other libraries to add some other functionality. This only produces the Ti*k*Z figure, it doesn't incorporate any library.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, positioning, shadings, arrows.meta}

\tikzset
  {
    ,my bubble/.style = 
      {
        ,draw=#1!70
        ,fill=#1!10
        ,ellipse
        ,inner sep=2pt
        ,minimum width=4em
        ,minimum height=2em
        ,align=center
      }
    ,my end/.style =
      {
        ,draw=#1!70
        ,top color=#1!10
        ,bottom color=#1!50
        ,minimum height=6em
        ,text width=6em
        ,inner sep=0pt
        ,align=center
      }
    ,my arrow/.style =
      {
        ,>=Stealth
        ,->
        ,draw=black
      }
  }

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=6em and 2em]
  \node[my bubble=blue] (Main) {Main};
  \node[my bubble=green,below left=of Main]   (T1) {Type-1\\\relax[4-6]};
  \node[my bubble=purple,below right=of Main] (T2) {Type-2\\\relax[8-10]};
  \path (Main) ++(0,-16em) node[my bubble=orange] (T3) {Type-3\\\relax[15-21]};
  %
  \node[my bubble=green, left=of T3]   (T1-3) {Technique-3\\\relax[5-6]};
  \node[my bubble=green, left=of T1-3] (T1-2) {Technique-2\\\relax[7-12]};
  \node[my bubble=green, left=of T1-2] (T1-1) {Technique-1\\\relax[2-6]};
  %
  \node[my bubble=purple, right=of T3]   (T2-1) {Technique-1\\\relax[15-17]};
  \node[my bubble=purple, right=of T2-1] (T2-2) {Technique-2\\\relax[12-14]};
  \node[my bubble=purple, right=of T2-2] (T2-3) {Technique-3\\\relax[19-21]};
  %
  \node[my bubble=orange, below left=of T3]  (T3-1){Technique-1\\\relax[15-20]};
  \node[my bubble=orange, below right=of T3] (T3-2){Technique-2\\\relax[22-25]};
  %
  \path (T3) ++(0,-16em) node[my end=red] (end) {My\\Technique};
  %
  %
  \draw[my arrow] (Main) -- (T1);
  \draw[my arrow] (Main) -- (T2);
  %
  \draw[my arrow] (T1) -- (T3);
  \draw[my arrow] (T2) -- (T3);
  %
  \draw[my arrow] (T1) -- (T1-1);
  \draw[my arrow] (T1) -- (T1-2);
  \draw[my arrow] (T1) -- (T1-3);
  %
  \draw[my arrow] (T2) -- (T2-1);
  \draw[my arrow] (T2) -- (T2-2);
  \draw[my arrow] (T2) -- (T2-3);
  %
  \draw[my arrow] (T3) -- (T3-1);
  \draw[my arrow] (T3) -- (T3-2);
  \draw[my arrow] (T3) -- (end);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I like this. However, it seems to require a separate document class. When I change the document class to letterpaper, it does not render. Unfortunately, I need it work within other document classes as this figure would appear within other stuff.

Comment: @shaun it does work with citations and it does work with `article` and the `letterpaper` option. It might need some reformatting or being displayed in landscape to fit the page, but it does work without throwing errors and does appear.