# Tikz graph with citations

Tags: tikz-pgf, citing, graphs

I am trying to create a graph whose nodes are some author-year citation from the bibliography. This question is very similar to [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/453980/graph-like-figure-with-citations-using-tikz) but, unfortunately, the answers provided suggest using the Forest package, which is meant to draw trees, or to manually position the nodes. Neither of those are convenient and I would really like to use the various tools and options of the algorithmic graph drawing capabilities of Tikz.

Simply using the \cite{} command inside a graph throws a missing \endcsname error. I have tried to remove some of the formatting done by the \cite command to fix this, without success.

I fear this is beyond my very limited Latex coding capabilities and any help would be appreciated.

Note that I would rather use bibtex to create the bibliography, but will welcome a transition to biber if it fixes the issue. I experimented with biblatex mostly to try the \citefield command.

Here is a MWE:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{testGraph.bib}
@book{BookA,
    author    = "A",
    title     = "A book",
    year      = 2000,
}

@book{BookB,
    author    = "B",
    title     = "B book",
    year      = 2002,
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}

\usepackage[%
  backend=bibtex,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{testGraph.bib}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeGraph}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}}
  {\thefield{title}}


\begin{document}

% Does not work

%\begin{figure}[h]
%\centering
%\tikz  \graph  {
%\cite{bookA} -> B
%};
%\end{figure}


% Does not work either...

%\begin{figure}[h]
%\centering
%\tikz  \graph  {
%{\citeGraph{Book1}} -> B}
%};
%\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[show/.style={draw}]
\node[show]    (bookA)    at    (0,0)    
    {\citeGraph{BookA}};
\node[show]    (bookB)   at     (3,0)    
    {\citeGraph{BookB}};
\draw[->]    (bookA) -- (bookB);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
\endinput
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nodes in a graph are given names that are identical to the content, and you can't name a node `\cite{...}`. To get around that use e.g. `A[as=\citeGraph{BookA}]`, then the node gets the name `A`, but the content `\citeGraph{BookA}`.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{testGraph.bib}
@book{BookA,
    author    = "A",
    title     = "A book",
    year      = 2000,
}

@book{BookB,
    author    = "B",
    title     = "B book",
    year      = 2002,
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}

\usepackage[%
  backend=bibtex,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{testGraph.bib}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeGraph}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}}
  {\thefield{title}}


\begin{document}

\tikz  \graph  {
A[as=\cite{BookA}] -> B
};

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```